# Find the end/finish coordinates you a UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I can find the start coordinates of where a swipe starts by doing the following

```
- (void)oneFingerSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{ 
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
NSLog(@"Swipe up - start location: %f,%f", point.x, point.y);
}
```

Is it possible to find the coordinates where the swipe ended?
I looked into the docs and its not mentioned. Is there some work around for this?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to examine the **state property** of the gesture recogniser

```
- (void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
   CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer view]];
   if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
       NSLog(@"began: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
   else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
       NSLog(@"ended: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> You need to examine the state property of the gesture recognizer

**WARNING**

It is incorrect because swipe gesture generates `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` event only.

The only way I found how to solve this issue is to use `touchesBegan:`. It works for current view only so additionally I should pass touches for example to parent views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`. And in there you have method:
`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

For more please read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint pt = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:view];
```

I believe this will give you the original x,y coordinates of the touch that initiated the gesture.